# Unsupported text language : natural language understanding API

Tags: php, ibm-cloud

I am using natural language understanding API of IBM cloud but language other than English gives me an error of unsupported language.

My Request parameter looks like as following:

```
        $url = "https://api.us-south.natural-language-understanding.watson.cloud.ibm.com/instances/****/v1/analyze?version=2017-02-27";
        $token = "apikey:****************";
        $token = base64_encode($token);
        $language = 'de';
        $bodyArray = [
            "text" => $text,
            "features" => [
                "syntax" => [
                    "sentences" => true
                ]
            ],
            "language" => $language
        ];

        $body = json_encode($bodyArray);
        $headers = [
            'Authorization' => 'Basic ' . $token,
            "Content-Type" => "application/json"
        ];

        $client = new Client();
        $request = new GuzzleHttpRequest('POST', $url, $headers, $body);
        $response = $client->send($request);
        $response = $response->getBody()->getContents();
```

Comment: Have you tried with automatic detection? And why is it `'de' or 'es'`?

Comment: Your `$language` is always `true`, maybe that's why it's not supported?

Comment: Yes, I tried automatic detection but it gives me the same error

Comment: You seem to use this request: https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/natural-language-understanding#analyze-text Add it to the question because there is also the GET request

Comment: as @Justinas pointed out $language is true. Since `'de' || 'es'` evaluate to `true`. So your parameter `language` is neither `de` nor `es`. Either leave out the language completely or just provide one language string.

Comment: In question, I showed my code of request parameter that I passed to API

Comment: additionally `syntax` has to be an object according to the docs, not an array.

Comment: @jdickel yes I leave out the language completely but the error remains the same it just works for the English language.

Comment: @jdickel json_encode() convert my array to object notation.

Comment: (https://i.ibb.co/p30LXC9/image.png) my error screenshot

Comment: Add your actual request including URI and headers

Comment: @data_henrik I modified my question see this

Comment: Have you tried with the current version? 2019-07-12

Comment: @data_henrik Yes, Now  I am trying this method but problem not solve

Comment: Ok. Reading the docs, "syntax" is an experimental feature. They are typically only supported for "en". https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/natural-language-understanding?topic=natural-language-understanding-about#syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The NLU feature for [syntax / sentences seems to be an experimental feature](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/natural-language-understanding?topic=natural-language-understanding-about#syntax) and hence only supported for the English language. That feature is not listed in the [language support for the GA features](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/natural-language-understanding?topic=natural-language-understanding-language-support).

Thus, I assume it is not working by design.